# Video flickers when HDMI monitor attached

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, hdmi

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 on my Dell Latitude E6520.

My video card:
VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119M [NVS 4200M] (rev a1)

When I plug in the HDMI cable for my second monitor, I get a lot of screen flicker.  The second monitor works, but the refresh rate is horrible (I get mouse trails like crazy).

For the record, this was not a problem with 12.10, and I didn't have to install any additional drivers with that OS -- it ran like a dream out of the box.  I'm not opposed to trying other drivers, just laying down the facts :)

Also for the record, I don't have another type of cable I can try at the moment -- I'm planning on picking one up today, will report back if it helps.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!  At some point during my OS reinstall, I managed to re-enable Optimus in the BIOS.  I disabled Optimus in the BIOS again, rebooted, and voila!  All is right with the world again.